# Error showing " ! Missing delimiter (. inserted)." when I am using \bigg

Tags: delimiters, compilation-error, parentheses

This code is bringing an error:

```
We get, $g\begin{pmatrix}r&0\\0&1/r\end{pmatrix}=\bigg\( g\begin{pmatrix}r&0\\0&1/r\end{pmatrix}\bigg\)^{-1}\Rightarrow g\begin{pmatrix}r&0\\0&1/r\end{pmatrix}=1$. So, $g$ is also trivial on $A$
```

I noticed that removing the \bigg resolves the problem. Please help

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The way to obtain a parenthesis is to type… `(` or `)`, not`\( ` and`\)` (which is a way to enter in-line math mode).  Also, you should use `\biggl`  and `\biggr`  for a correct spacing of `left` and `right` delimiters.

Comment: I actually want a big parenthesis, so what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in my comment, use this:

```
$g\begin{pmatrix}
r & 0 \\ 0 & 1/r
\end{pmatrix}
=\biggl(g\begin{pmatrix}
r & 0 \\ 0 & 1/r
\end{pmatrix}\biggr)^{-1}
\Rightarrow g\begin{pmatrix}
r & 0 \\ 0 & 1/r
\end{pmatrix}=1$
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I understood what you wanted to say.